# Toastr rails using importmaps in rails 7

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

I am having trouble displaying my toast messages in rails using importmaps default setup. This is my code.

This is my layout file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Toastr</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<% if flash[:notice].present? %>
<script type="module">
toastr.success("<%= notice%>");
</script>
<% end %>
  <p style="color: green"><%= notice %></p>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my importmap.rb

```
# Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin "application"
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
# NOTE: pin jquery to jsdelivr instead of jspm
pin "jquery", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.js"
```

This is my application.js

```
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "jquery";
console.log($);
console.log(jQuery);
```

In application.js, it gives me console that means jquery is loaded.

Now whenever there is a flash messages, it gives me this error

```
toastr.js:474 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend')
    at m (toastr.js:474:40)
    at Object.i [as success] (toastr.js:474:40)
    at 13:2:8
```

When I add a jquery cdn in application.html.erb also, then this error is gone, I dont know why because I already leaded my jquery in application.js